# two ajax calls are not running simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two ajax calls using jquery, The first one should take time around 20 seconds to be executed, but the second one is much faster, should be executed in Milliseconds. What is happening is the second ajax call is not finishing executing until the first one is complete, once the first call is executed, the second ajax is executed fast. So the second ajax is being called with the first one but it doesn't finish executing until the first one is complete. How can I fix that ?

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (e) {
        do_download();

    });
    function do_download()
    {
        $('.status p').text('Fetching the video ...');
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.example.com/download/start",
            method: "POST",
            async: true,
            data: {youtube_url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ic7scBTY-xw',
                    access_token :'4b5e0c903eb7b68eb336500cdfc2d11c'
                }
            });

            request.done(function (msg) {
                //alert('done');


            });

            request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
            });
    }


    var get_operation_status_interval = setInterval(get_operation_status, 1000);

    function get_operation_status() {
        var url_process_info = "http://www.example.com/download/get_video_status_new/ic7scBTY-xw";
       $.ajax({
            url: url_process_info,
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            method: "GET",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.progress){
                    $('div.meter span').css('width', data.progress);
                    if( data.progress == '100%' && data.is_file_ready != false){
                        $('.status p').text('Converting the video ...');
                    }
                }
                if (data.is_file_ready == true) {
                    clearInterval(get_operation_status_interval);
                    $('.status p').text('file is ready !');
                    $('.download-section').show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a race condition. You have this:

do_download: setting ajax call as async
get_operation_status: setting ajax call as sync

so, the first function that you call is "get_operation_status", why?? Because do_download will be call when document will be ready but the other function will be call before, so, browser takes time to have the document ready, then first call is "get_operation_status" and this function freeze other calls because it's sync instead of async:

```
// tames some time, it's no inmediately
jQuery(document).ready(function (e) {
    do_download();
});

// this call could be execute before do_download
var get_operation_status_interval = setInterval(get_operation_status, 1000);
```

Put both calls async (never never never SYNC) and the timer inside document ready as:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (e) {
    do_download();
    var get_operation_status_interval = setInterval(get_operation_status, 1000);
});
```

Comment: I've moved the set interval with the function to the document ready as you mentioned, but still not working, here is snapshot from firebug http://screencast.com/t/fYdn7W5b

Comment: Here is a snapshot when I set the two calls to async = true, the second ajax has been called many times but none got executed until the do_download is done http://screencast.com/t/qnxwmVVGov

Comment: Ok, one question, are you using some alert on your code? Please, try removing all "alert" function because is a sync function and block the main javascript thread.

Comment: The issue seems to be with the codeigniter, I re asked the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31212362/ajax-callings-to-functions-in-the-controller-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd one is async: false. Change it to true.(or remove it completely)

Comment: I set the second call async: false, it calls it multiple times but none of the call  finished  executing until the first call is done