# ajax callings to functions in the controller codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 3 and I am having a strange issue using ajax. I'm trying to call two ajax simultaneously and I thought I have problem with my ajax code and I asked  this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209699/two-ajax-calls-are-not-running-simultaneously) and nothing worked with me.

I kept making the code more simple and narrow it down until I discover that the problem seems to be with the codeigniter

Here is my js code:

```
        do_download();
        get_operation_status();

        function get_operation_status() {
            //var url_process_info = "http://www.example.com/public/sleep_status.php";// this url works as expected 
            var url_process_info = "<?php echo site_url(); ?>download/sleep_status";

            $.ajax({
                url: url_process_info,
                dataType: 'json',
                async: true,
                method: "GET",
                success: function (data) {

                },
                complete: function (){
                    get_operation_status();

                }
            });
        }


        function do_download(){
            //var download_url = "http://www.example.com/public/sleep_download.php"; // this url works as expected 
            var download_url = "<?php echo site_url(); ?>download/sleep_download";

            $.ajax({
                url: download_url,
                method: "POST",
                async: true

            });
        }
```

My php code, inside the Download controller, I have these two functions just for testing :

```
 public function  sleep_status () {
        sleep(1);
    }
    public function sleep_download(){
        sleep (7);
    }
```

Calling the ajax to the controller download, it showing the issue which keeps the second call pending until the first one is executed.

I created two php files  and put them in /public/sleep_download.php and /public/sleep_status.php

and within the two files just the sleep line of code, and it works as I want, while the first call is running, the second ajax call has been excuted several times .

**Edited:** I could make it work by making the class not extending from CI_Controller, I created a new class named Action and I commented this part:

```
class Action /*extends CI_Controller*/ {
```

Although I could make it work, I still wonder why was it happening ? and is there a better solution ?

Comment: Isn't the problem sleep related which just pauses execution so the other function can't be run. Have you tried doing something other than sleep?

Comment: @noveyak Yes, my original code was doing something else, I just replaced with the sleep to make accurate estimating of the calls, Although sleep functions are working fine when I can them from the php files in the public directory.

Comment: Yeah I've encountered this issue before. From what I saw it seems codeigniter locks for that user until the previous function completes. I've struggled to find an answer for this question as well, so interested to see what people have to say.

Comment: @Schultzie I edited the question, I could make it work by avoiding the extending from CI_Controller

Comment: basically CI all request go through main `index.php` that means your both ajax request executes same php file(`index.php`) not two php file. so your 2nd request will execute after first execute completes.

Comment: @Kamal but if you don't extend CI_Controller, then you do not have access to any codeigniter functions correct?

Comment: @Schultzie I didn't extend the CI_Controller and I could access the functions, I'm not sure why.